# Oracle - Deleting or inserting rows via cursor

Tags: oracle

Apologies in advance, I am occasional Oracle user. I have put together a lookup table used by various functions/procedures and need to keep refresh this once a day with rows that either need removing or inserting. I have put together the following simply queries that return the columns against which I can determine the required action.  Once I have returned my deletion data, I then need to delete from table A all records where the site_id and zone_ids match. I cant figure out the best way to achieve this, I have thought about running the select statements as cursors, but am not sure how I then delete the rows from table A using the site_id and zone_id from each record returned.

## Query That returns records to be deleted from Table_A

```
SELECT site_id,zone_id,upper(ebts_switch_name)
FROM Table_A
minus
    (SELECT site_id,zone_id, upper(ebts_switch_name)
    FROM Table_B@remote_db
    UNION
    SELECT site_id,zone_id,upper(ebts_switch_name)
    FROM Table_C);
```

## Query That returns records to be Inserted into Table_A

```
SELECT cluster_id, site_id,zone_id, upper(trigram),upper(ebts_switch_name)
FROM Table_B@remote_db
WHERE site_id is NOT NULL
minus
SELECT cluster_name,site_id,zone_id,upper(trigram),upper(ebts_switch_name)
FROM Table_A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your statements directly in the manner shown below:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_A
  WHERE (SITE_ID, ZONE_ID, UPPER(EBTS_SWITCH_NAME)) IN
    (SELECT site_id, zone_id, upper(ebts_switch_name)
       FROM Table_A
       minus
         (SELECT site_id, zone_id, upper(ebts_switch_name)
            FROM Table_B@remote_db
         UNION
         SELECT site_id, zone_id, upper(ebts_switch_name)
           FROM Table_C));

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (CLUSTER_NAME, SITE_ID, ZONE_ID, TRIGRAM, EBTS_SWITCH_NAME)
  SELECT cluster_id, site_id, zone_id, upper(trigram), upper(ebts_switch_name)
    FROM Table_B@remote_db
    WHERE site_id is NOT NULL
    minus
    SELECT cluster_name, site_id, zone_id, upper(trigram), upper(ebts_switch_name)
    FROM Table_A;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Minor typo: It should be `Table_A MINUS ( Table_B UNION Table_C )` not `Table_A MINUS ( Table_B UNION Table_A )` (which would delete nothing). Edit: just noticed that that was the OP's mistake originally.

Comment: Thanks for update Bob, this meets my needs I think I was over working this in my mind.  I will add to procedure that is called by Perl script and use dbms output to grab and log rows updated.

Comment: @MT0 - I'd noticed that too, but hey - who am I to argue? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what do you mean by first query, cause it's almost same as

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_a
MINUS
SELECT *
  FROM table_a
```

means empty record set.

But generally, use `DELETE` syntax

```
DELETE
  FROM table_a
 WHERE (col1, col2) IN (SELECT col1, col2
                          FROM table_b);
```

And `INSERT` syntax

```
INSERT INTO table_a (col1, col2)
     SELECT col1, col2
       FROM table_b;
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I will adopt answer supplied by Bob above -- Sorry for confusion I have updated the delete statement the union should have been with 3rd table not table_A as initially entered.